# Blank Screen After installing Ubuntu server 14.04 on Dell Poweredge T20

Tags: server, screen, vmware

I have a problem of Blank screen after installing Ubuntu Server 14.04 on Dell T20 server, actually while installing there is no F6 options but while installing in the VMWare i am getting the F6 option to set nomodeset.

And at the same time i dont have reputation to post screenshots

Please help in fixing this

Thanks in advance